# When the group interaction in multiple regression is not significant, shall we include the group variable in the following regression models?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, group-differences

I want to explore the relationship between biological markers and cognition in healthy controls and patients. In order to determine if the relationship varies between groups, I included the interaction term in the model first as **Cognition =  Biological markers + Group + Group * Biological markers + other covariates** and there is a lack of significant group interaction effect. Therefore, I plan to explore the relationship in all subjects as **Cognition =  Biological markers + other covariates**. My question is should I include **Group** in this new model? More specifically, if there are significant group differences in **Cognition** and **Biological markers** between healthy controls and patients, **Group** is highly likely contributing to **Cognition**.

Answer (score 0):

An "insignificant" `Group * Biological markers` interaction coefficient doesn't mean that `Group` by itself has an "insignificant" association with outcome. The "insignificant" interaction just means that you couldn't distinguish an *extra* association of outcome beyond what you could explain based on `Group` and `Biological markers` individually. Certainly you should include `Group` as a predictor if you have reason to believe that it might be associated with outcome.

If you have enough data, I would recommend also maintaining the interaction term in your model even though it isn't "statistically significant" based on an arbitrary *p*-value cutoff. The interaction still might be *important* enough to improve the estimates of the associations of the other variables with outcome. See Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/), especially Chapter 4, for the advantages of fitting a complex model provided that you don't overfit the data.